# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker' from mapbox-gl-csp-worker.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-worker, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am using mapbox gl's csp [distribution](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/overview/#csp-directives). Instead of using the script tag, I am using its node module.

After importing the mapbox gl, I tried to set its workerUrl in my index.ts:

```
mapboxgl["workerUrl"] = "https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.10.1/mapbox-gl-csp-worker.js";
```

(I am using the bracket notation instead of mapboxgl.workerUrl because I got *Error: Illegal reassignment to import* from rollup.)
When I loaded my example code on chrome, I got the following error:

```
 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.10.1/mapbox-gl-csp-worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.
```

When I ran the code from localhost on chrome, I still got the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.10.1/mapbox-gl-csp-worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8887'.
```

When I ran the code from localhost on firefox, I got the following error:

```
Security Error: Content at http://localhost:8080/dist/2.0/examples/example.html may not load data from https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.10.1/mapbox-gl-csp-worker.js.
```

Is this a known issue in mapbox or am I missing anything? Thank you!